# What is the function of "their way" in "they went their way"?

Tags: objects, adverbials, grammatical-roles, transitivity

*Go* is clearly an intransitive verb. [This source {Chomp Chomp_Robin L. Simmons}](https://chompchomp.com/terms/intransitiveverb.htm#:%7E:text=Some%20verbs%2C%20such%20as%20arrive,logical%20direct%20object%20to%20follow.) says:

> Some verbs, such as *arrive, **go**, lie, sneeze, sit, and die*, are always intransitive; it is impossible for a logical direct object to follow.

However, you do hear such exceptions as *[to die a thousand deaths](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dying+a+thousand+deaths)*, where *die* does become transitive.

In this sentence:

> And they that were sent ***went their way***, and found even as he had said unto them. (Luke 19:32 KJV)

where *to go one's way* is not used with the meaning of something going the way you want it, but literally taking one's leave, what is the function of ***their way***? Is it a direct object? Or is there an omitted preposition *on* at the origins of the phrase?

This phrase was rather common in past centuries:

> Jeers and scornful laughter followed him out of the igloo, but his jaw was set and ***he went his way***, looking neither to right nor left. (*[Love of Life and Other Stories](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/710/710-h/710-h.htm)*, by Jack London)

And even earlier:

> Well, ***go thy way***: thou shalt not from this grove
>  Till I torment thee for this injury. 
> My gentle Puck, come hither. (*[A MIDSUMMER NIGHT'S DREAM](https://A%20MIDSUMMER%20NIGHT%27S%20DREAM)*, Shakespeare)

Is it possible for ***go*** to have ever been transitive in the past?

Comment: There's a question on [go home](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429853/what-is-the-part-of-speech-of-home-in-the-sentence-go-home) which is relevant; some answers also mention "go down", "go south", etc.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: That source is wrong. The Oxford English dictionary provides several definitions of "go" as a transitive verb.

Comment: *Their way* is volitional. But *send* doesn't take a volitional object, so the light verb *went* is foisted on us to enable the volitional NP. "... the semantic contribution goes beyond that of the purely functional tense/aspect kind. While light verbs generally do signal some kind of boundedness or telicity or causation (crosslinguistically), they also go beyond that and signal volitionality, benefaction, forcefulness, surprise, etc." https://ling.sprachwiss.uni-konstanz.de/pages/home/butt/main/papers/harvard-work.pdf

Comment: "Boris Johnson — the ex-mayor of London who once said he may have tried cocaine but then accidentally sneezed it all out"  https://www.online-translator.com/contexts/english-russian/sneezed

Comment: Could you step back and consider two things about 'And they that were sent went their way, and found even as he had said unto them'?

First, how is that now, or was it 400 years ago, a real English sentence? Ignoring that, how could '…they that were sent went their way …' work?

Doesn't English demand that either "they went their way" or "they went the way they were sent" and never the twain shall meet? (I hope I'm not pointlessly repeating Phil Sweet…)

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I work with texts written in KJV and Shakespearean language and to me it makes perfect sense. Also I know the context well. "They that were sent" can be replaced today by "Those whom [Jesus] had sent [to do what was mentioned in the preceding verse]". It basically means "those who were sent".

Comment: Yes, if the point is '… to do what was mentioned before.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *And they that were sent went their way, and found even as he had said*
> *unto them*.

I don't see any reason why the NP "their way" should not be considered direct object of "went".

Comment: I'm a little surprised to see just how consistent the ratio of usage with / without preposition ***on*** has been over the past two centuries. It's become *slightly* more common to include the preposition over recent decades, [but not much](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+went+their+way%2Cthey+went+on+their+way&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). Obviously the choice only exists with ***to go*** - we never could say *It's getting late, so **I'll be / get my way***.

Comment: The idiom _send/go (on) one's way_ allows optional _on_. Though you're right, it sure looks like a direct object. Passivizes with or without _on_: _The way (on which) they were sent runs through Throckmorton_.

Comment: @JohnLawler I wish this would be clearer in the dictionaries and grammars. Many of them proclaim that go can never be transitive... Just discovered that [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go) does an excellent job with that!

Comment: Transitivity is a sometimes thing. The relation between the verb and its object is the most variable semantic bond in English. Every verb defines what can be its object; that's part of its meaning, it's so specialized. Like pollinator species and flower species, they're delicately attuned.

Comment: @John Lawler I think we've been here before, but doesn't the passivisation test lead to 'a good time' being classed as a DO in 'All had a good time' but 'a ball' etc not being a DO in 'All had a ball'?

Comment: It's one test among many, but in idioms with auxiliaries like _have_ it doesn't show much. The point I was trying to make was that _can_, like all modals, is its own thing and has to be taken as that and not as an exemplar of some category or other.

Comment: @JohnLawler Because *this way* is not an object of the verb but an adverbial adjunct in *You can figure it out **this way***, I see little reason to consider it such in *He went **this way***, either. Surely we can still use noun phrases adverbially  even after losing their customary old genitive case designation seen in *He threw the ball **quite a good ways***. [See OED about this particular case with *way(s)*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226469#eid15116082).

Comment: @tchrist - up to you; I don't care, really. If it makes money to consider it an object, fine. Otherwise, why bother designating anything you don't have to?

Answer (score 2):

'Go' is not intransitive in all its uses. It may be used intrasitively most of the time, but it is quite obviously not exclusively intransitive.

> go the distance
>
> go two days without food
>
> go this way / that way
>
> go a ways
>
> go someplace nice
>
> go both ways
>
> go all in
>
> go this alone
>
> go another step
>
> Go me!
>
> I'll go you one better.

The only argument I can think of against calling the above objects is that most cannot be passivized. Still, they're complements to the verb ***go*** and have the form of an NP.

Comment: Is "Go me!" part of this list? I feel it should've been "Go, me!"

Comment: Passivisation is not an infallible test (unless you define terms to make it so). 'A good time was had by all' is idiomatic, while 'A ball was had by us' is outlandish. // Allerton, in 'The Handbook of English Linguistics'... eds Aarts and McMahon, claims that post-verb noun groups such as appear in

_The piano resembled a pianola.

The piano weighed a ton.

The piano had a stool.

The piano seemed an antique._

should not be considered objects but are 'best regarded as belonging to a slightly different category'.

Comment: Most of those look like adverbial adjuncts to me, not object complements. [See OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226469#eid15116082).

Comment: @tchrist Although some might want a different term, as most of them seem obligatory. As with 'Put the bottle [on the table].' 'I didn't think It would go [the distance].' 'I decided to go [it alone] and stay and run the farm.'

Answer (score 1):

Your source is incorrect. The Oxford English Dictionary lists 12 different definitions of "go" as a transitive verb (granted, some are obsolete). The relevant definition in this case is 20b.

> **20 b**. *transitive*. To set off on (one's way or course of travel). Chiefly in ***to go one's way.*** Now somewhat *archaic*

Comment: Yes, it is clearly incorrect. Here is another [source](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/intransitive_verbs.htm) that classifies it as intransitive. They really should mention that it can be both...

Answer (score 0):

"their way" is unneeded in your example, but may be useful if 'they' go their separate ways, their own way, or some other notable way

in this context go is meaning "travel off along" or something similar

Comment: My question is if "their way" _**is**_ there, what function does it have?

Comment: none, as I said; it sort of retroactively makes go use the other sense, where go means "travel off along (some path)", but adds no extra information, because the only thing communicated about the "way" is that it is "theirs".

If you need the right sentence structure jargon, I can't be of any help

Answer (score 0):

## Adjunct, not Object

The grammatical function of *their way* in

> They went their way.

is that of ***adverbial adjunct***, not that of direct object. No action is received by that noun phrase.

Remember that noun phrases can be used adverbially, usually designating time, distance, or location. Doing so does not make them objects:

1. He waited **three minutes**.
2. He walked **three miles**.
3. He went off **a little ways** and waited **an hour**.

You can still see the vestige of the Old English genitive case in that last example, where we use *-s* for the adverbial use of *a way*.

That particular instance the OED discusses [here](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226469#eid15116082) under “P3. Adverbial phrases containing the form *ways* with a singular determiner”. But the singular form can also be used **this way**, and it remains adverbial.

Comment: Maybe, but in "He walked three miles", I'd say that the NP "three miles" is object, particularly as it can be passivised, as in "The last three miles had to be walked".

Comment: Interesting approach. Your OED link is inaccessible to those who do not have membership. It may be helpful to summarise what it says about _going one's way_, not "ways", if possible.