# Visit it vs Visit there

Tags: word-choice

1: Darkhan has changed. The city's skyline rose with the construction of new structure, expanding the urban landscape. When I visited **it** ....

2: Darkhan has changed. The city's skyline rose with the construction of new structure, expanding the urban landscape. When I visited **there** ....

Comment: Save yourself wondering, go with *When I visited ...*

Answer (score 2):

Both are acceptable. In my opinion, "there" is a little better because Darkhan is a place, and "there" is a pronoun specific to places, while "it" is usually used for concepts or tangible objects.

Idiomatically, I think "went" is the more common verb used in this context. In this case, "went it" is not acceptable, although "went to it" would be (but it sounds weird to me). On the other hand, "went there" is very normal. You can even omit the object entirely, "When I went, ...", as it's understood from the context.

Answer (score 2):

*She visited it.*
*She visited there.*

As others have said, both are acceptable, though *it* would be more common, especially in British English.

Grammatically, the pronoun *it* would serve as a direct object, while *there,* according to [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), is a locative preposition serving as a goal complement.

Finally, as has also been pointed out, you can also omit the dependent altogether, and just say *she visited.*

## Discussion

### Acceptability

Here are some examples of both, from the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

*Krajnyak, 48, was originally from Hungary and had just **visited there,** according to her Facebook page and a neighbor.*

*"This place is like a series of living Post covers—and I'm in it," he told a young man who also **visited there.***

*… including immediate access to the bin Laden compound and to three of bin Laden's wives and other individuals who were known to have lived or **visited there.***

*Marcus Stephen is the president of Nauru, a coral blip in the midst of the vast Pacific with a population of less than 14,000 and with only 21 square kilometers of real estate. It is the smallest independent republic in the world. "There are not many countries you can bicycle around before breakfast," wrote the BBC correspondent Nick Squires, who **visited there** earlier this year.*

*Having lived in Detroit for a period in our lives, we **visited there** frequently and found Habatat.*

*There is a life-sized recreation of a saloon after Carrie Nation **visited it** with her signature axe.*

*Cristina West, who primarily works at the fudge counter in the same shop, was first "blown away" by the convenience store when she **visited it** on her honeymoon.*

*However, ISPs do know that you visited that website, when you **visited it,** how long you stayed there, and how much data went back and forth.*

*Playwright Tennessee Williams also had a house in Key West. Ornithologist James Audubon has a house named after him, although he never **visited it.***

*Enchanted by the campus when he **visited it** as a commencement speaker in the early 1900s, Nutting invited Berea carpentry instructors to his factory in Framingham, Massachusetts, to learn furniture-making skills.*

And here are some examples of *visited* without any dependents.

*Black Hawk College was in Moline, Illinois, and Hillary had never **visited.***

*She would jump all over just about anyone who **visited.***

*Stephens is Nassar's only known nonmedical victim, who he assaulted in the basement of his home on weekends while their families **visited.***

*Its release would belie Saudi claims that no such delegation **visited.***

*The black shades in the dining room were all closed during the evening we **visited.***

### Distribution

In COCA, *visited it* has 151 hits, while *visited there* has 105. Meanwhile, in the British National Corpus [(BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/), *visited it* has 46 hits, whereas *visited there* has only 6. Similar patterns emerge when one looks at google NGrams (first restricted to [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visited+it%2Cvisited+there&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) and then to [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visited+it%2Cvisited+there&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)), confirming that 1. they are both acceptable in both dialects; 2. *visited it* is more common than *visited there* in both dialects; but 3. the preference for *visited it* is stronger in British English than in American English.

### Grammar

*It* is uncontroversially a pronoun, and serves as a direct object of *visited*.

The status of *there* is more controversial, in the sense that the [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468)'s analysis differs from that of traditional grammar. I will present CGEL's analysis.

According to CGEL, the *there* in *…visited there* is a 'locative' *there,* and is an **intransitive preposition.** Here 'intransitive' means that, unlike prototypical prepositions, it has no object, no complement (CGEL, p. 272).

<sup>The locative *there* is not to be confused with the 'dummy' *there,* which, although historically derived from the locative *there,* is nowadays a pronoun. For example, in the sentence *There is nothing there,* the first *there* is the dummy *there,* and the second *there* is the locative *there* (CGEL, p. 1391).</sup>

The grammatical function of the locative *there* is that of a **goal complement.**

**Discussion**

The way to see that *there* in *visited there* is a complement (rather than a modifier) is that it is licensed by the verb. For example, while it is acceptable to say *she visited/sat/wrote there,* it is not acceptable to say *<sup>*</sup>she heard there* or *<sup>*</sup>she said there.*

As far as why, according to CGEL, the locative *there* is a proposition, this is a longer story, which I can only briefly sketch.

***Why the locative* there *is a preposition***

CGEL's argument proceeds in two steps. First, they argue that a certain group of words that **can** take an optional dependent are prepositions both in sentences in which they do take a dependent and in sentences in which they do not. Second, they argue that a *second* group of words (and *there* belongs to this second group) is syntactically just like the first group, except that members of this second group can't take dependents. The conclusion is that the members of this second group (*there* included) should also be classified as prepositions.

So, let's start with the first step.

Let's look at the following pair of sentences:

*The owner is not **in the house***
*The owner is not **in.***

The traditional grammar would say that the first *in* is a preposition, while the second is an adverb. CGEL argues that we should say that both instances of *in* are prepositions, for several reasons.

(i) There is no principled basis for insisting that prepositions can't appear without a complement. We don't impose such restrictions for verbs (*she was **eating an apple*** vs *she was **eating***), nouns (*she's **the director of the company*** vs. *she's **the director***), or adjectives (*I'm **certain it's genuine*** vs *I'm **certain***). Now look at, for instance,  *I haven't seen her **since the war*** vs. *I haven't seen her **since***. What principled reason could there be for saying that while the first *since* is a preposition, the second couldn't be, because it has no dependents?

(ii) Regardless of whether the NP complement is present or not, the same modifiers are permitted. Examples: *two hours* in *he'd left [two hours before the end]* vs. *he'd left [two hours before]*; *straight* in *she went [straight inside the house]* vs *she went [straight inside]*.

(iii) These patterns are not merely found only with marginal items, or just occasionally with one or two prepositions. Rather, they are found systematically, with some of the most typical prepositions: *aboard, about, above, across, after, against, along, alongside, apropos, around, before, behind, below, beneath, besides, between, beyond, by, down, for, in, inside, near, notwithstanding, off, on, opposite, outside, over, past, round, since, through, throughout, to, under, underneath, up, within,* and *without.*

Therefore, CGEL concludes, all these words should be taken as prepositions regardless of whether they appear with a complement or not (CGEL, pp. 612­­–613).

Now comes the second step in CGEL's argument.

Consider words in the following category, which includes the locative *there*. These are spatial terms that take no complements: *abroad, abreast, adrift, aground, ahead, aloft, apart, ashore, aside, away, here, there, where, hence, thence, whence, east, north, south, west, aft, back, forth, home, together, downhill, downstage, downstairs, downstream, downwind,* and some others.

Syntactically, these words are very similar to the prepositions from the first list (*aboard, about, …*) except that they don't take complements. For example, compare *they went/are aboard* and *they went/are ashore.* Some of these can be modified by *right* and *straight,* e.g. *they are right downstairs* or *we went straight indoors.* CGEL concludes, 'We accordingly include these too in the preposition class'  (CGEL, pp. 613­­–615).

Comment: Also interesting (and relevant to the one example): you can "live there" but you can't "live it" (not if "it" is a place at least).

Answer (score -2):

**Visit it**

Visit is most commonly a transitive verb, meaning it expects an object. In option #1, the object is "it", Darkhan.

In option #2, "there" is being treated as an object, but "there" is traditionally an adverb and cannot be an object.

Comment: "Visit" can also be used as an intransitive verb, so in fact "visit there" is perfectly fine.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there) lists "there" as also a pronoun and noun as in "Hi there" or "Take it from there". It certainly doesn't seem odd to have it follow a verb like "look there", "go there", "sit there", etc. Although there are problems classifying parts of speech in such expressions: see also the questions about "[go home](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429853/what-is-the-part-of-speech-of-home-in-the-sentence-go-home)".

Comment: @alphabet Agreed, but why would someone pick one over the other here?

Comment: I would pick "there" because it's specific to places, while "it" is usually used for things.

Comment: @Barmar The answer is bad, but I would prefer “it”, because “visit there” seems unnatural to me.  But it may be British/US usage, like “visit with”.